# Why are Wolverine and Kitty Pryde headmaster and headmistress?

Tags: comics, marvel, x-men, wolverine, wolverine-and-the-x-men

I've just started reading the Wolverine and X-Men series without reading all the backstory and was wondering how on earth it was these two that ended up heading the new school, especially Wolverine?  I would have thought there were much better and more suitable options available amongst the X-Men.

Comment: You mean like people who actually have an education?

Comment: @JackBNimble - education is overrated. I have a CS graduate degree and no SciFi degree. Guess which site I'm barely top 400th or so user on and which #1.

Comment: If only there was a way to actually make a living out of being a colossal trek nerd... :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for the duo to be headmaster and mistress is that: 
1. Kitty Pride represents respectability and a defensive face for the public. 
2. The Wolverine represents a mutant whom all mutants respect for his power and prior acts. 
 This is discussed in the first couple issues of Wolverine and the X-Men prior to the state inspectors showing up.

Comment: It may be worthwhile to take stock of the mutants who went with Logan to found the Jean Grey academy; afaik, the only mutants more qualified to lead a new school were either still in San Fran or dead.

Answer (score 4):

After the events of [X-Men: Schism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men%3a_Schism) the team split into two groups.  I won't go into the ideologies that led to the split (as it's a fairly new storyline that I don't want to spoil), but Cyclops now leads a group of X-Men based in Utopia (an island off the California coast) while Wolverine leads a group at the School for Gifted Children back in New York.

Answer (score 2):

There may be X-Men who are better suited as leaders, but Wolverine has historically settled himself into a role of mentor or older-brother to a number of younger members. Kitty Pryde and Jubilee were probably the best examples of this. Becoming a headmaster is something that actually seems right up his alley.

As I recall, Kitty is one of the few members who actually went off and studied at a more traditional (read: non-mutant) college. This also seems like a reasonable fit.